# How can you have a "large header" in NativeScript?

Tags: ios, nativescript

I am exploring using Vue + NativeScript for my next project and I was wondering how the following can be implemented

[image: large header switch animation]

using the `ActionBar` element (or something else) because I can't find the flags to allow that capability.  I am basically looking for an equivalent for [NativeStackNavigator](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/blob/487b8cdab1398c20846f2207c098a7404c6854c6/createNativeStackNavigator/README.md)'s `headerLargeTitle` which is implemented *natively* (no custom animation).

Comment: The example is more complex than your question. Are you asking how to set action bar? how to make a text with dynamic font size? how to align  to paragraphs when the upper is bigger than the lower?

Comment: well on iOS there's already a native API that handles that resizing which NativeStackNavigator is using.  I want to utilize the same API.

Comment: Well, can't you listen to the scroll event and change the font size accordingly? Or just bind the font size and the scrolled value?

Comment: Because that's customization, I want to use the native iOS API.